# SwiftUI show loading view while core data is being loaded

Tags: core-data, swiftui

How I can show loading view while core data is being loaded?.

Currently my app's core data store some many images in Binary Data. So when I switch to another tab showing data stored in core data, app lags 1.5 seconds.

So here are two things I have tried:

1. first I tried to minimize amount of data being loaded from core data using downsample function:

```
func downsample(imageAt imageURL: Data, to pointSize: CGSize, scale: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.scale) -> UIImage? {
        
        // Create an CGImageSource that represent an image
        
        //CGImageSourceCreateWithData(_ data: CFData, _ options: CFDictionary?)
        let imageSourceOptions = [kCGImageSourceShouldCache: false] as CFDictionary
        guard let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(imageURL as CFData, imageSourceOptions) else {
            return nil
        }
        
        // Calculate the desired dimension
        let maxDimensionInPixels = max(pointSize.width, pointSize.height) * scale
        
        // Perform downsampling
        let downsampleOptions = [
            kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailFromImageAlways: true,
            kCGImageSourceShouldCacheImmediately: true,
            kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailWithTransform: true,
            kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize: maxDimensionInPixels
        ] as CFDictionary
        guard let downsampledImage = CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex(imageSource, 0, downsampleOptions) else {
            return nil
        }
        
        // Return the downsampled image as UIImage
        return UIImage(cgImage: downsampledImage)
    }
```

```
let small = downsample(imageAt: data, to: size)
Image(uiImage: small!)
```

But there were no difference in lagging time.

2. So i tried this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \ToDoItem2.createdAt, ascending: false)])
    var toDoItems: FetchedResults<ToDoItem>

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            if toDoItems.isEmpty {
                LoadingView()
            } else {
                List {
                    ForEach(toDoItems) { item in
                        ToDoItemView(item: item)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Tried to detect no loaded state as `toDoItems.isEmpty` but it doesn't work

Would be there anyway to show loading view while core data is being loaded?
Thanks

Comment: `imageURL: Data` is it being expected as Data? or a local image file?

Comment: It's being expected as Data

Comment: check the way you load the Data to memory, if it take time, move the process to background queue

Comment: have a look at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchrequest/1506622-fetchlimit or search for core data fetch limit here on SO. Also you should think about compressing your images when you save them.

Answer (score 0):

you could try using `NSAsynchronousFetchRequest`, something like this approach (does not have to be exactly like this (untested) code):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @State private var toDoItems: [ToDoItem] = []
    @State var isLoading = true
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if isLoading {
                LoadingView()
            } else {
                List {
                    ForEach(toDoItems) { item in
                        ToDoItemView(item: item)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            isLoading = true
            let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<ToDoItem> = ToDoItem.fetchRequest()
            fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \ToDoItem.createdAt, ascending: false)]

            let asyncFetchRequest = NSAsynchronousFetchRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequest) { fetchResult -> Void in
                if let resutls = fetchResult.finalResult {
                    self.toDoItems = resutls
                }
                self.isLoading = false
            }

            do {
                _ = try viewContext.execute(asyncFetchRequest)
            } catch {
                print("error: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```